# PHP Soap API - Create Custom Object Record - No fields provided in an external foreign key reference in entity

Tags: custom-object, php, enterprise, enterprise-wsdl, php-toolkit

Relatively new to working with the Salesforce API. Trying to create a new record for a custom object we have created in Salesforce. Below is the code I am using to create this custom object, I am making sure I am using the API names for the object itself as well as for the fields.

```
<?php

$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP-master/soapclient");

require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

try {

  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($username, $password);

  $sObject = new stdclass();
  $sObject->First_name__c = 'Test';
  $sObject->Last_name__c = 'Test';
  $sObject->Email__c = 'test@test.com';
  $sObject->RecordType = "MyCustomRecordType";
  $sObject->Name = "API Testing";

  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'CustomObject__c');

} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e);
  echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
}

?>
```

The error I am receiving from this code is the following:

```
No fields provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: RecordType
```

This is how the standard fields for the object looks like in Salesforce.

[image]

I made sure my RecordType name matches that of the record type configured in Salesforce.

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by running the API call

```
describeSObject
```

against my custom object. Looking through the result, I noticed that the record type field's name was instead

```
RecordTypeId
```

There was also a list of all record types and their ID's in this API call, something I did not see when browsing my record type in the Salesforce UI.

So instead of

```
$sObject->RecordType = "MyCustomRecordType";
```

I am now using

```
$sObject->RecordTypeId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```